# При docker-compose pull выдает Warning и Error

Tags: docker

По инструкции https://github.com/denverquane/automuteus#docker-compose делаю команду

**docker-compose pull**

на что получаю:

WARNING: The AUTOMUTEUS_REDIS_ADDR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 

WARNING: The BROKER_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

ERROR: Missing mandatory value for "image" option in service "galactus": err**

при этом в sample.env данные переменные заполнены.

Прописывая переменные в   kitematic в settings-> general -> environments variables и  docker-compose pull ошибка остается актуальной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `sample.env` -> `.env`

Comment: спасибо. помогло

Answer (score 0):

export AUTOMUTEUS_REDIS_ADDR=123.123.123.123

export BROKER_PORT=1234

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]